# Draw and fill a rectangle in iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I have 4 points say (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x2,y3) and (x4,y4). I need a draw a rectangle with these points and fill a color inside that rect. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UIBezierPath` object. Move to your first point, then call `addLineToPoint:` for your subsequent three points. Then call `closePath`.

You can now `fill` or `stroke` this path, or obtain the `CGPath` if you want to use core graphics.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) for the documentation.

Answer (score 24):

First, get the current graphics context:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Next, define the rectangle:

```
CGRect myRect = {x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1};
```

Now, set the fill color, e.g red

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Set the stroke color, e.g. green:

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Finally, fill the rectangle:

```
CGContextFillRect(context, myRect);
```

Comment: Two down votes on this today. No comments provided. Any thoughts?

Comment: wow another two down votes on this answer and again no comments. Not brave enough to provide feedback?

Comment: `CGContextFillRect` will not draw a border, you also need to add a `CGContextStrokeRect`.

Answer (score 1):

If You need the same for swift 4.2:

```
  func drawOldStyle() {

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else{
            return
        }


        //Next, define the rectangle:
        let myRect = CGRect(x: 30, y: 100, width: 100, height: 20)

        //Now, set the fill color, e.g red
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)

        //Set the stroke color, e.g. green:
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)

        //Finally, fill the rectangle:
        context.fill( myRect)

        // AND Stroke:
        context.stroke(myRect)

    }
```